# Hide SDXC Card from desktop

Tags: external-data

how to hide an SDXC card from the desktop without ejecting it?  I would like to have the SDXC card show in Finder, but NOT on the desktop.  Is there a way to make it available in the finder?  If I eject it, it does not show, but to get it back I have to restart the computer.

Answer (score 1):

Finder Preferences  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>,</kbd>   > General
Uncheck External Disks.

[image]

It will still appear in Devices in the Sidebar, unless you have those hidden too, but will not appear on the Desktop.

Pics showing what changes...

On.

[image]

Off.

[image]

Comment: Still does NOT work.  I have unchecked as described, but noting has changed.  I even rebooted, with no change.  Maybe it works for a USB hard drive, but it does NOT work for SDXC.

Comment: Tested with an SD card. Result is immediate.

Comment: Please tell me what I may be doing wrong.

Comment: Please tell me what I may be doing wrong.  I go to finder, preferences, general, and uncheck External Disks.  Nothing changes.  I still see the SDXC on my desktop!  Do I somehow need to save the change?  If I reboot the changes (External Disks) still is Unchecked!  Help!

Comment: Edit to show just what changes - finder windows & sidebar remain unaltered, icon disappears from Desktop itself. It's a live update - now you see it, now you don't.